# OutOfMemoryError (GC overhead limit exceeded) but still a lot of free space

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

In our Tomcat application, we get an "OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded".
But `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` reports 576 MB are free.

How can this happen?

The error is thrown from within the SQL Server JDBC driver, and I cannot imagine this would try to allocate hundreds of megabytes in one memory request.
And the `GarbageCollectorMXBean`s counts for "PS Scavenge" as well as "PS MarkSweep" did not increase much in the minutes before the error was thrown.

`Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` as well as `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` report 4.5 GB. This is running with the 64 bit Sun JVM for Java 7.

Comment: Please paste the entire stack trace - did it go out of memory due to heap exhaustion or perm gen. or something else...

Comment: This answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1393503 - it explains the meaning of this particular OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Does your application do `System.gc()` by any chance?

Answer (score 6):

"GC overhead limit exceeded" means that your heap is not exhausted, but that the amount of CPU time spent on garbage collection has exceeded a predefined limit. Basically, your JVM is doing little else besides collecting garbage. This may be caused by a variety of reasons, the most typical being that the heap is *nearly* exhausted, but every major GC manages to squeeeze out just enough to satisfy the allocation request.

In your case there may be other causes, such as an enormous heap size along with too many major GC's. You will need to investigate your situation with a diagnostic tool. I highly recommend `visualgc`.

Comment: I find it hard to believe it can happen with more than 512 MB declared free :/

Comment: @fge Agree, but nevertheless the answer and the recommendation to use some diagnostic tool is absolutely correct :)

Comment: @Andreas I am not denying it ;)